# Is this right (no "equals")?

Tags: traducción

In Mark Twain's "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn" this appears:

*I had been to school most all the time and could spell and read and write just a little, and could say the multiplication table up to six times seven 
is thirty-five,*

The Spanish translation is this:

*Había ido a la escuela casi todo el tiempo, me sabía las letras y leer y escribir un poco y me sabía la tabla de multiplicar hasta seis por siete treinta y cinco,*

Is the Spanish really "....six times seven thirty-five" (rather than "...six times seven IS or EQUALS thirty-five")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para empezar me imagino que te habrás dado cuenta de que *six times seven* **IS NOT** *thirty-five* but *forty-two*.

En una frase aislada si sería necesario el verbo, pero si la multiplicación forma parte del "recitado" de la "tabla de multiplicar" es habitual omitir el verbo.

Así, al *cantar* la tabla (de multiplicar) del seis, lo normal es decir:

> seis por uno, seis;
>   seis por dos, doce;
>   seis  por tres, dieciocho;
>   ...
>   seis por siete, cuarenta y dos;
>   ...

Comment: Si, por supuesto (6X7 no es 35)